# Rspecs for Sub APP and Main APP in Padrino

Tags: rspec, mongoid, integration-testing, padrino

Is there any good way to test a controller and model of Sub APP in Padrino with rspec? I am a newbie experimenting with Padrino and Mongoid ORM. Can anyone provide me the link for examples showing rspecs for Sub APP and Main APP in Padrino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch `@app`

`@app = Admin.tap { }`

or

`@app = YourApp.tap { }`

Comment: Can You give a quick example how can I swith the app() ?